# How to simulate a loop's 'break' statement inside an array-iterating, custom implemented, 'forEach' function/method?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, break, continue

What is the best way to implement a simulation of a loop's `break` statement, when one does iterate through a user/engine defined function?

```
forEach([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], function (n) {
  console.log(n);
  
  if (n === 2) {
    break;
  }
});
```

I've thought of implementing `forEach` in a way that would break when the function returns `false`. But I would like to hear thoughts on how that is normally done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return`ing `false` is the most common way to do it. That's what jQuery's iterator function [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) does:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return **false**. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

And its *very* simplified implementation:

```
each: function( object, callback ) {
  var i = 0, length = object.length,
  for ( var value = object[0]; 
        i < length && callback.call( value, i, value ) !== false; // break if false is returned by the callback 
        value = object[++i] ) {}
  return object;
}
```

Comment: This answers the question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Since the OP explicitly did ask for ***"simulating ... `break` ... inside ... `forEach`"***, and since the language core now has much more features than 11½ years ago, one actually could implement quite easily a prototypal array method which not only enables a `break` but also a `continue` command, similar to both statements [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) and  [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue).

In order to achieve the implementation of the iterating array method, one first needs to write some abstractions which do borrow the basic idea from [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/AbortController) and its related [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal).

Thus, one would implement e.g. a `PausedStateSignal` ...

```
class PausedStateSignal extends EventTarget {
  // shared protected/private state.
  #state;

  constructor(connect) {
    super();

    this.#state = {
      isPaused: false,
    };
    connect(this, this.#state);
  }
  get paused() {
    return this.#state.isPaused;
  }
}
```

... which is going to be used by its `PauseController` ...

```
class PauseController {
  #signal;
  #signalState;

  constructor() {
    new PausedStateSignal((signal, signalState) => {

      this.#signal = signal;
      this.#signalState = signalState;
    });
    this.#signalState.isPaused = false;
  }
  get signal() {
    return this.#signal;
  }

  break() {
    const isPaused = this.#signalState.isPaused;

    if (!isPaused) {
      this.#signalState.isPaused = true;
    }
    this.#signal.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('break', { detail: { pausedBefore: isPaused } })
    );
    return !isPaused;
  }
  continue() {
    const isPaused = this.#signalState.isPaused;

    if (isPaused) {
      this.#signalState.isPaused = false;
    }
    this.#signal.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('continue', { detail: { pausedBefore: isPaused } })
    );
    return isPaused;
  }
}
```

... where `PausedStateSignal` has to extend [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget) in order to be able of signaling state-changes via [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), and where `PauseController` features the two main methods `break` and `continue`.

Both implementations are relying on [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntax, [private properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_properties), [`get` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#using_getters_in_classes) and a private, protected `state` object which gets shared by reference in between a controller and a signal instance. The latter gets achieved by a `connect`ing callback function which is passed at a signal's instantiation time.

Having covered that part, one can continue with the actual implementation of an array method which, in addition of the standard `forEach` functionality, is capable of three things ...

- allowing to **pause/halt the callback function's execution** via `break`,
- and via `continue` allowing ...

  - either to **continue a paused/halted loop**,
  - or to **skip the loop's next iteration step**.

The implementation could be named e.g. `forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue`; it does make use of the above described signal and controller abstractions, might look like follows ...

```
function forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue(callback, context = null) {
  const { promise, reject, resolve } = Promise.withResolvers();

  const controller = new PauseController;
  const { signal } = controller;

  const arr = this;
  const { length } = arr;

  let idx = -1;

  function continueLooping() {
    while(++idx < length) {

      if (signal.paused) {
        --idx;

        break;
      }
      try {
        callback.call(context, arr.at(idx), idx, arr, controller);

      } catch (exception) {

        reject(exception.message ?? String(exception));
      }
    }
    if (idx >= length) {

      resolve({ success: true });
    }
  }
  signal.addEventListener('continue', ({ detail: { pausedBefore } }) => {
    if (pausedBefore) {
      // - continue after already having
      //   encountered a break-command before.
      continueLooping();
    } else {
      // - continue-command while already running which
      //   is equal to skipping  the next occurring cycle.
      ++idx;
    }
  });
  continueLooping();

  return promise;
}
```

...  and finally gets assigned for demonstration purposes via [`Reflect.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/defineProperty) as `forEachAsyncBC` to `Array.prototype` ...

```
Reflect.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'forEachAsyncBC', {
  value: forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue,
});
```

The now prototypal `forEachAsyncBC` method is always going to return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This [`Promise` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) either [`reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)s or [`resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)s; the former in case the provided callback function does raise an error at any time it gets invoked, and the latter in case the iteration cycle has been fully completed.

Thanks to all the abstractions an executable example code which does test all of the mentioned features can be written as easy as that ...

```js
(async () => {

  const result =  await [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    .forEachAsyncBC((value, idx, arr, controller) => {

      console.log({ value, idx });

      if (value === 9 || value === 3) {
        console.log(`... skip over next value => ${ arr[idx + 1] } ...`);

        // skip over.
        controller.continue();

      } else  if (value === 4 || value === 6) {

        console.log(`... break at value ${ value } ... continue after 5 seconds ...`);
        setTimeout(controller.continue.bind(controller), 5000);

        // break loop.
        controller.break();
      }
    });

  console.log({ result });

})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>

class PausedStateSignal extends EventTarget {
  // shared protected/private state.
  #state;

  constructor(connect) {
    super();

    this.#state = {
      isPaused: false,
    };
    connect(this, this.#state);
  }
  get paused() {
    return this.#state.isPaused;
  }
}

class PauseController {
  #signal;
  #signalState;

  constructor() {
    new PausedStateSignal((signal, signalState) => {

      this.#signal = signal;
      this.#signalState = signalState;
    });
    this.#signalState.isPaused = false;
  }
  get signal() {
    return this.#signal;
  }

  break() {
    const isPaused = this.#signalState.isPaused;

    if (!isPaused) {
      this.#signalState.isPaused = true;
    }
    this.#signal.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('break', { detail: { pausedBefore: isPaused } })
    );
    return !isPaused;
  }
  continue() {
    const isPaused = this.#signalState.isPaused;

    if (isPaused) {
      this.#signalState.isPaused = false;
    }
    this.#signal.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('continue', { detail: { pausedBefore: isPaused } })
    );
    return isPaused;
  }
}

// - asynchronously implemented `forEach` array method which
//   provides a `PauseController` instance as 4th parameter
//   to its callback function, where the latter's two methods
//   `break` and `continue` enable the following ...
//
//    - pause a `forEach` loop by invoking `break`.
//    - by invoking `continue` ...
//       - either continuing a paused `forEach` loop.
//       - or skipping the `forEach` loop's next iteration step.
//
function forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue(callback, context = null) {
  const { promise, reject, resolve } = Promise.withResolvers();

  const controller = new PauseController;
  const { signal } = controller;

  const arr = this;
  const { length } = arr;

  let idx = -1;

  function continueLooping() {
    while(++idx < length) {

      if (signal.paused) {
        --idx;

        break;
      }
      try {
        callback.call(context, arr.at(idx), idx, arr, controller);

      } catch (exception) {

        reject(exception.message ?? String(exception));
      }
    }
    if (idx >= length) {

      resolve({ success: true });
    }
  }
  signal.addEventListener('continue', ({ detail: { pausedBefore } }) => {
    if (pausedBefore) {
      // - continue after already having
      //   encountered a break-command before.
      continueLooping();
    } else {
      // - continue-command while already running which
      //   is equal to skipping  the next occurring cycle.
      ++idx;
    }
  });
  continueLooping();

  return promise;
}

Reflect.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'forEachAsyncBC', {
  value: forEachAsyncBreakAndContinue,
});

</script>
```